# Let's learn some soil pH chemistry!

Tags: code-golf, string, chemistry

Andrew is a chemist, interested in the acidity of solutions and in agriculture. After months of research (Google is not his friend), he came up with the following table* regarding the human-readable level of acidity in terms of the [pH (potential of Hydrogen)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH#pH_in_soil):

```
         Denomination        |         pH range
                             |
    -------------------------+-----------------------------   
    Ultra acidic             |          below 3.5
    -------------------------+------------------------------
    Extremely acidic         |    between 3.5 and 4.4
    -------------------------+------------------------------
    Very strongly acidic     |    between 4.5 and 5.0
    -------------------------+------------------------------
    Strongly acidic          |    between 5.1 and 5.5
    -------------------------+------------------------------
    Moderately acidic        |    between 5.6 and 6.0
    -------------------------+------------------------------
    Slightly acidic          |    between 6.1 and 6.5
    -------------------------+------------------------------
    Neutral                  |    between 6.6 and 7.3
    -------------------------+------------------------------
    Slightly alkaline        |    between 7.4 and 7.8
    -------------------------+------------------------------
    Moderately alkaline      |    between 7.9 and 8.4
    -------------------------+------------------------------
    Strongly alkaline        |    between 8.5 and 9.0
    -------------------------+------------------------------
    Very strongly alkaline   |          over 9.0
```

Given a non-negative decimal number representing the pH of a substance, output its Denomination. You can take input and provide output by [any standard method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). The data types you are allowed to take input with are:

- Float
- Double
- Your language's standard decimal number data type
- String

And you must output a String representing the denomination. Built-ins related to chemistry are forbidden *(Sorry, Mathematica!)*.

***Approximation Rule:*** If the pH you receive is between an upper bound of a denomination and the lower bound of the next one (e.g. between 7.8 and 7.9), it gets approximated to the closest value between the two: if the pH ≥ upperBound of the first + 0.5, then it should receive the second denomination, but if the pH < upperBound of the first + 0.5, then it should receive the first one (e.g 7.85 is approximated to 7.9, but 7.84999 is approximated to 7.8). See the test cases for clarifications.

## Test Cases:

```
Input ->  Output

6.40  ->  Slightly acidic
8.399 ->  Moderately alkaline
3.876 ->  Extremely acidic
10.60 ->  Very strongly alkaline     
0.012 ->  Ultra acidic
7.30  ->  Neutral
7.85  ->  Moderately alkaline (the approximation rule is applied)
7.849 ->  Slightly alkaline (the approximation rule is applied)
6.55  ->  Neutral (the approximation rule is applied)
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid submission (in bytes) wins!

<sub>**Andrew did not come up with that, it was [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH#pH_in_soil)!*</sub>

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/12971#12971) for those who can see deleted posts.

Comment: yeah this doesn't really work with actual acidity levels. anything more acidic than lemon juice is ultra acidic

Comment: @DestructibleLemon If lemon juice is Ultra acidic, then [Fluoroantimonic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluoroantimonic_acid), that behaves like having −31.3 is a total atomic bomb :))

Comment: oh, I see where you went wrong. 3.5 ph is not ultra acidic, but it is ultra acidic if the soil you are growing plants in is 3.5 ph. what I mean is, this table refers to soil ph

Comment: @DestructibleLemon That's what this challenge is about: soil pH :)... This is totally what I intended :§

Comment: Brownie points for an answer in Python or Swift :)

Comment: How isn't [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] suited for this? You must compress the denomination strings...

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder if the problem were to print the table, that would be a kolmogorov-complexity problem. But since the problem is to take a number as input and return a string, this is not a kolmogorov-complexity problem (I could be wrong about this, but that's the answer I got on one of my past posts)

Comment: @musicman523 Ok, I was really confused

Comment: Can you add `3.49` and `9.01` as test cases as the outer limits are differents from the inner ones

Comment: Is the input restricted to being a valid value of "your language's standard decimal number data type"?

Comment: IMHO there should be a category, like "mapping", for this kind of challenge. It's basically "map elements in this specific set onto this other set".

Comment: @immibis  Yes, you are guaranteed that the value is valid

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder So if I use Boolfuck again, where the standard data type is a bit, the input can only be 0 or 1 (decimal)?

Comment: @immibis I really do not know what to say about this, but I will allow it.

Comment: I feel like it should be natural logarithm of hydronium....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>77 73</s>  71 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“£RĿÐƭðṚ°ƲṂṾẒ=ʂXḣsịɠ<»Ḳµ,Ṛ;€"“¡D⁺“a&»j“¿<z»W¤ṙ3
×20<“FYeoy³ƓɗʋṆ‘Sị¢⁾. y
```

A monadic link taking the number and returning a list of characters; or a full program printing the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDi4OO7D884djawxse7px1aMOxTQ93Nj3cue/hrkm2p5oiHu5YXPxwd/fJBTaHdj/csenQVh2gKutHTWuUQHoXujxq3AVkJKod2p0FEthvU3Vod/ihJQ93zjTmOjzdyMAGKOoWmZpfeWjzscknp5/qfriz7VHDjGCgmYcWPWrcp6cAdMZ/QwM9MwA)**

#### How?

```
“ ... »Ḳµ,Ṛ;€"“¡D⁺“a&»j“¿<z»W¤ṙ3 - Link 1, name list: no arguments
“ ... »                          - compression of "Ultra Extremely Very.strongly Strongly Moderately Slightly"
       Ḳ                         - split at spaces
        µ                        - monadic chain separation, call that adjectives
          Ṛ                      - reverse adjectives
         ,                       - pair these two lists
              “¡D⁺“a&»           - compression of [" alkaline"," acidic"]
             "                   - zip with:
           ;€                    -   concatenate for €ach
                             ¤   - nilad followed by links as a nilad
                       “¿<z»     -   compression of "Neutral"
                            W    -   wrap in a list
                      j          - join
                              ṙ3 - rotate left by 3: ["Strongly alkaline","Moderately alkaline","Slightly alkaline","Neutral","Slightly acidic","Moderately acidic","Strongly acidic","Very.strongly acidic","Extremely acidic","Ultra acidic","Ultra alkaline","Extremely alkaline","Very.strongly alkaline"]

×20<“FYeoy³ƓɗʋṆ‘Sị¢⁾. y - Main link: number, pH
×20                     - multiply by 20
    “FYeqy³ƓɗʋṆ‘        - code-page indexes = [70,89,101,111,121,131,147,157,169,180]
   <                    - less than? (vectorises)
                        -   i.e.: pH < [3.5,4.45,5.05,5.55,6.05,6.55,7.35,7.85,8.45,9]
                S       - sum
                  ¢     - call last link (1) as a nilad
                 ị      - index into (1-indexed and modular)
                        - ...note that the sum is never 11 or 12, so "Ultra alkaline" and
                        -    "Extremely alkaline" wont be fetched, but that a sum of 0
                        -    fetches "Very.strongly alkaline", as required.
                   ⁾.   - literal list of characters ['.', ' ']
                      y - translate (replace any '.' with a ' ' i.e. for "Very.strongly")
                        - if running as a full program, implicit print
```

Comment: I always enjoy competition between 05AB1E and Jelly... Only 2 bytes away

Comment: Jelly beats 05AB1E?!?!

Answer (score 5):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 199 bytes

```php
foreach([35,9.5,6,5,5,5,8,5,6,5.5]as$l)$p+=$argn*10>=$s+=$l;$p-=$argn==9;echo[Ultra,Extremely,"Very strongly",Strongly,Moderately,Slightly][$p>6?12-$p:$p],[" acidic",Neutral," alkaline"][1+($p<=>6)];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYwxT8MwFIT3/orI8pDQ14hQJaK4TgeUgYEyFFiiqLJSE1uY@OnFSGThr4cQ0C13n@4ODU77AxqMVprI05k0egq27@Lv6nx8en64rxKx4oq6XrJtmjMxvXnSqjVxvc1hl@ZQQL7oFhaf5o0auEs4ruWyu8quS8mHOTnBcfMHpdwJ3Rpfv7hACqqvQPpDuxHYq6YxGgL5vnMjg9O/g0d/0aTCb@fkbGeCG5uaY1kcspsNxzuODdQsUq292JbBUX/Oxw5m4t6Vs71mTZ2tY457WRZJI6bpBw)

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 236 bytes

```cs
p=>{var l=new[]{70,89,101,111,121,131,147,157,169,180,280};var a="Ultra,Extremely,Very strongly,Strongly,Moderately,Slighty, acidic,Neutral, alkaline".Split(',');int i=0;for(;p*20>=l[i];i++);return i==6?a[7]:i<6?a[i]+a[6]:a[12-i]+a[8];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVPBbtswDL3nK4Reai@qKjuJ7VR1dhi20zoMCLYdDB9UW0mJKpIhy12NIN@eyZmTotgKxIcSoECK4uMjCRX1VaGN2CMnheR1jb4bvTZ8M@putoezk9pyCwV60lCiOw7K80@hl0edLNvaig350qjittTNvRTYJRtQ6wVaoXS0r9LF9okbJFMlfmf5NqY4meOABjgInIZOJ06nMQ5mTiMXSygOE7pjXRpPL35Iazj@/GyN2AjZ4p/CtF0NrdbOWx6NO10Kw233Yilh/WBbjHgBJRT4m2gchHS@fOQSlLggy0qC9S7xpc9AWQQpZSttPFZ9COkilRnkDMZjnxlhG6NcPI0@8izOb@C2MyAf8yzKb3gWhFcHJ8nZbs9G/xvOJ61qLQX5ZcCKr668t/IiMqW@z9D1NfrLVrY923MREjKZz3uIl95PLZ4LMyFJHPUwpxkPpBJQEh27ebWdwWwooUHYIx32PpBJTCZHIv3Sz89MZm9PE3n2QSBeVUY/w8b9Da2QaaRAUHe3EkTpD6g0nf@z@3coFJHZ7PUwBqHvDtZu/wc)

This solution considers that `p` cannot be greater than 14.

Answer (score 4):

## T-SQL, <s>305</s> 299 bytes

```
DECLARE @ char(999)=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('SELECT TOP 1i FROM(VALUES(''Very s$#9&S$#8.4&Moderately#7.8&Slightly#7.3&Neutral'',6.5&Slightly@6&Moderately@5.5&S$@5&Very s$@4.4&Extremely@3.4&Ultra@-1))x(i,j),t WHERE j<a','#',' alkaline'','),'@',' acidic'','),'&','),('''),'$','trongly')EXEC(@)
```

Input is via a pre-existing table *t* with `DECIMAL(4,1)` column *a*, [per our Input/Output rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

Because of the `DECIMAL(4,1)` data type, any "approximation rule" rounding takes place when the value is entered into the input table, so doesn't need to be explicitly managed by my code.

After the space-saving `REPLACES` are performed, this is a simple SQL query joining our input table with our list of values:

```
SELECT TOP 1 i
FROM(VALUES
    ('Very strongly alkaline',9),
    ('Strongly alkaline',8.4),
    ('Moderately alkaline',7.8),
    ('Slightly alkaline',7.3),
    ('Neutral',6.5),
    ('Slightly acidic',6),
    ('Moderately acidic',5.5),
    ('Strongly acidic',5),
    ('Very strongly acidic',4.4),
    ('Extremely acidic',3.4),
    ('Ultra acidic',-1)
) x(i,j), t
WHERE j<a
```

I reverse the order so `TOP 1` picks the first one less than our input value.

Even this form (after removing line breaks and extra spaces) is pretty good, at **318 bytes**. Adding the overhead of the `DECLARE`, `REPLACES` AND `EXEC` only becomes worth it with all the repeated phrases.

**EDIT**: Save 6 bytes by removing unnecessary ".0" on several values

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>81</s> <s>80</s> <s>79</s> <s>77</s> <s>76</s> 74 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

```
'Äˆ“¢³¿™ly³¾‚Òw““³¾§ÓªÅ“«#Â¦¦’šÉaƒ£’«Š’w¡Îic’«)˜™'wð:I•t{~À•ST+.¥70+20/‹Oè
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f/XDL6bZHDXMOLTq0@dD@Ry2LciqBjH2PGmYdnlQOFAdJAfmHlh@efGjV4VYQd7Xy4aZDyw4te9Qw8@jCw52JxyYdWgxkH1p9dAGQKj@08HBfZjJYQPP0HKCJ6uWHN1h5PmpYVFJdd7gBSAeHaOsdWmpuoG1koP@oYaf/4RX//5vrWZgCAA)

[Test suite](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9T9l/9cMvptkcNcw4tOrT50P5HLYtyKoGMfY8aZh2eVA4UB0kB@YeWH558aNXhVhB3tfLhpkPLDi171DDz6MLDnYnHJh1aDGQfWn10AZAqP7TwcF9mMlhA8/QcoInq5Yc3WFU@alhUUl13uAFIB4do6x1aam6gbWSg/6hhp//hFf8rlQ7vt1I4vF9J57@ZnokBl4WesaUll7GehbkZl6GBnpkBl4GegaERl7mesQGQsDAFESaWXGZ6pqYA)

**Explanation**

```
'Äˆ                   # push the string "neutral"
“¢³¿™ly³¾‚Òw“         # push the string "slightly moderately strongly veryw"
“³¾§ÓªÅ“              # push the string "strongly extremely ultra"
«                     # concatenate the top 2 items on the stack
 #                    # split on spaces
  Â                   # push a reversed copy
   ¦¦                 # remove the first 2 elements of the copy ("ultra", "extremely")
’šÉaƒ£’«              # append the string "walkaline" to each ("walk"+"a"+"line")
        Š             # move down 2 places on the stack
’w¡Îic’«              # append the string "wacidic" to each ("w"+"acid"+"ic")
        )˜            # wrap stack in a list and flatten
          ™           # title case each
           'wð:       # replace each instance of "w" with a space
I                     # push input
 •t{~À•               # push the base 255 compressed number 920006021
       ST+            # split to list of digits and add 10 to each
          .¥          # undelta (compute increments from 0)
            70+       # add 70 to each
               20/    # divide each by 20
                  ‹   # compute input less than for each
                   O  # sum
                    è # use this to index into list of strings
```

Comment: This is surprisingly long for 05AB1E

Comment: Late to the party, but still curious: does anyone directly program in this language (even if only for code golfing) or is this the output of some sort of a "compiler" ?

Comment: @avl42: We code directly in this language yes (generally only for golfing of course). I'd hate to see someone use this in production code ;) It is an interpreted language so code you write in this language gets interpreted to python code.

Comment: @Emigna I'd say "translated" rather than "interpreted" (it's kind of opposite meaning)

Comment: @anatolyg: Yes, you are correct there. I always think interpreted for some reason, probably due to python. It is translated into an interpreted language :)

Comment: Would have been better for my sanity, if the line noise were the *result* of some translation, not the outset ;-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 228 bytes

```
$
.00
\.(.)\.?(.).*
$1$2
.+
$*
1{900,}
VA
1{845,}
STA
1{785,}
MA
1{735,}
SLA
1{655,}
Neutral
1$
1 acidic
1{605,}
SL
1{555,}
M
1{505,}
ST
1{445,}
V
1{350,}
Extremely
1+
Ultra
M
Moderately
V
Very sT
T
trongly
L
lightly
A
 alkaline
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc0/a8MwEAXw/X0KDw6kSTlOseU/U8lQusRd6nrKEJGIVER1QFWhofSzuydnefx4Ot0FG91opsXy5TDlIGbsaUkPe3qSpBVylW9Aa@QrqN@W@fEPw1bYlFr41ifXTXI3s5jrXXKlk1/tdwzGQ@VQmTm6kzumN77PCfU81iXdy15YzusHUaHTzeefGOyn9TeoNd69bJQf3fVkg4mpHTDYcMu@evSI4TqepdvBu/NHFG2RGX8x3o12mioqGQ0VbYuCmrqCYqoYTKw2qKlgiUanKFtUpPU/) Link includes test suite. Explanation:

```
$
.00
\.(.)\.?(.).*
$1$2
```

Multiply the input by 100 by suffixing a spare decimal point and two zeros then deleting the decimal point and all but two digits after it.

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
1{900,}
VA
1{845,}
STA
1{785,}
MA
1{735,}
SLA
```

Handle all the alkalis, converting into abbreviations that will be expanded later.

```
1{655,}
Neutral
```

Handle neutral.

```
1$
1 acidic
```

Anything left must be acidic. (But leave the 1 in case the pH is 0.001)

```
1{605,}
SL
1{555,}
M
1{505,}
ST
1{445,}
V
1{350,}
Extremely
1+
Ultra
```

Handle all the acids.

```
M
Moderately
V
Very sT
T
trongly
L
lightly
A
 alkaline
```

Expand the abbreviations.

Comment: Wow, I think it took a while to golf it down...

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 202 bytes

*-15 bytes thanks to @JonathanAllan*

```python
lambda k:'Neutral_Slightly_Moderately_Strongly_Very strongly_Extremely_Ultra'.split('_')[abs(sum(round(k*10)>ord(i)for i in'",27<AINT')+(k>9)-(3.45<k<3.5)-6)]+(' acidic'*(k<6.55)or' alkaline'*(k>=7.35))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU09b8IwEN37K05dbENiBYJDEoVIHTp0KAu0C0XIEAesODFyjNQI8dtTG6k3vHt3eh/XwV50Nx/r1c@oeHusODQ5WoubNVwdNkqeL1YNh09dCcOtcHRjje7OjnwLM0D/f73/WiNaL/hSzotof1XSYnRAZMePPe5vLTb61lW4mcwiUmpTYUlqbUCC7NBrMF8Wbx/rLSJT3JQZCXFMF6xoipgyEiZkP8UI@ElW8oQmuCkSyhjRxv1Uw5XshP@WqyWNGSGjz7Wity4adgldBJDSOMsCiGm6TAKYRdRhRKPZPADn8ZCyJy6cyod7reeZE@3zF3BzNbKzgO45e0BYwv2BqCtqucW@K4D6uV39Hw)

Comment: You took my brownie points.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>192</s> <s>189</s> <s>185</s> 184 bytes

```js
k=>([...'09544474540'].some(n=>(i--,k-=++n)<0,i=7,k=k*10-33.5),'Neutral,Slightly,Moderately,Strongly,Very strongly,Extremely,Ultra'.split`,`[i<0?-i:i]+(i?i>0?' acidic':' alkaline':''))
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

k=>([...'09544474540'].some(n=>(i--,k-=++n)<0,i=7,k=k*10-33.5),'Neutral,Slightly,Moderately,Strongly,Very strongly,Extremely,Ultra'.split`,`[i<0?-i:i]+(i?i>0?' acidic':' alkaline':''))

console.log(f(6.40))  //  Slightly acidic
console.log(f(8.399)) //  Moderately alkaline
console.log(f(3.876)) //  Extremely acidic
console.log(f(10.60)) //  Very strongly alkaline     
console.log(f(0.012)) //  Ultra acidic
console.log(f(7.30))  //  Neutral
console.log(f(7.85))  //  Moderately alkaline
console.log(f(7.849)) //  Slightly alkaline
console.log(f(6.55))  //  Neutral
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 240 bytes

```
=CHOOSE((A1<6.55)+(A1<6.05)+(A1<5.55)+(A1<5.05)+(A1<4.45)+(A1<3.5)+(A1>=7.35)+(A1>=7.85)+(A1>=8.45)+(A1>9)+1,"Neutral","Slightly","Moderately","Strongly","Very Strongly","Extremely","Ultra")&IF(A1<6.55," acidic",IF(A1>=7.35," alkaline",""))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript, <s>222</s> 209 bytes

```js
x=>'Very strongly,Strongly,Moderately,Slightly,Neutral,Extremely,Ultra'.split(',',7,x-=0.049)[x>9?0:x>8.4?1:x>7.8?2:x>7.3?3:x>6.5?4:x>6?3:x>5.5?2:x>5?1:x>4.4?0:x>3.5?5:6]+(x<6.5?' acidic':x>7.3?' alkaline':'')
```

Still golfing it a little

```js
var f = x=>'Very strongly,Strongly,Moderately,Slightly,Neutral,Extremely,Ultra'.split(',',7,x-=0.049)[x>9?0:x>8.4?1:x>7.8?2:x>7.3?3:x>6.5?4:x>6?3:x>5.5?2:x>5?1:x>4.4?0:x>3.5?5:6]+(x<6.5?' acidic':x>7.3?' alkaline':'')

console.log(f(6.40));
console.log(f(8.399));
console.log(f(3.876));
console.log(f(10.60));
console.log(f(0.012));
console.log(f(7.30));
console.log(f(7.85));
console.log(f(7.849));
console.log(f(6.55));
```

Comment: I don't think you need to assign the function to a variable.